# How can I solve a time out error in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am working with load testing in Jmeter and Blazemeter and I apply it in two different versions of the web application. One is the test version and the other is the production version. My script works fine in test version but not in the other one. Here I get some petitions that throw errors like this:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:113)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity.writeTo(StringEntity.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:156)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:238)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$5.doSendRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:392)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:843)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:574)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I change the timeout values of the petition that throw that error but it does not work. It gives me this error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:843)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:574)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am new to jmeter. I do not know how to solve this. Maybe it is not an error of my script. Still... do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're running into situation described in [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JMeterSocketClosed) article from [Apache JMeter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/Home) Wiki

According to the article the reasons could be in:

> Retry or stale check can hide issues on Server configuration:
>
> - Server failing to send the (optional) Keep-Alive header
> - Overwhelmed server refusing connection, retrying would increase load

So I would recommend

- to check whether your production version is really sending [Keep-Alive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive) header in particular and compare the response headers from test and production environments in general:

  [image]
- to ensure that the application has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network sockets, etc., it can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)

If you're absolutely sure that your application behaviour is correct you can amend JMeter properties as it's described in the Wiki page to tolerate potentially incorrect system under test setup.

- In *user.properties* file add the next lines:

  ```
    httpclient4.retrycount=1
    hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
  ```
- In *hc.parameters* file add the next lines:

  ```
    http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
  ```